# Hörmander condition extension to the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

This is the local property for the solution to be infinitely smooth. However, I can't see the result that relates the regularity inside of the domain and the regularity at the boundary, at least not in the Hörmander original paper (1967) on hypoellipticity...Can I say that if the condition is satisfied inside of the domain and I do obtain a $C^{\infty}$ regularity(because the operator is hypoelliptic) inside, it is at least continuous up to the boundary as well?

Say I am looking at the PDE $u_t=x^2u_{xx}+xu_y$, if I rewrite the diff.operators in the formm of the Hörmander I can see that the system is of rank $3$ and thus it is hypoeeliptic which says it is $C^{\infty}$ inside of the domain, but can I extend that to the boundary continuously as well?

Comment: yes, I have finished it now.

Comment: sorry, I have added all the context

Comment: Corrected the spelling error in Lars Hörmander's name - fully realizing that many of us are working with diacriticaly challenged keyboard. Including yours truly (who would have trouble with some French/Spanish/Latvian accents or Danish/Norwegian diphtongs).

Comment: @Jyrki I find HTML codes like  &ouml; easier to remember than other input methods. They work in posts but not in comments (not sure about titles). // Medan : I deleted my comments about incompleteness.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I don't currently have access to the Hormander paper, so I don't know if this satisfies all your conditions, but consider, for example, the equation
$$\Delta U + \frac{1-2\gamma}{y} U_y = 0$$
on the upper half space $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ (that is to say, points $(x,y)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}_+$). In any domain compactly contained in the interior of $\mathbb{R}^n_+$, the coefficient functions are smooth and bounded, so $U$ is a $C^\infty$ function. However, consider that $y^{2\gamma}$ is always a solution to this equation, and consider the cases where $\gamma < 0$, then $U$ explodes to infinity on the boundary of the domain.